# MX google maps loads insecurely over https

Tags: mx-google-map

MX Google Maps does not display in a channel form when the page is loaded over HTTPS. I get the error:

```
The page at 'https://www.fakesite.com/members/manage-listing/474' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

It also stops all of my other JavaScript from running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit the file `/system/expressionengine/expressionengine/third_party/mx_google_map/ft.mx_google_map.php` and change the following lines

On line 135, change:

```
ee()->cp->add_to_foot('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>');
```

To

```
ee()->cp->add_to_foot('<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>');
```

and on line 856, change:

```
ee()->cp->add_to_foot('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>');
```

To

```
ee()->cp->add_to_foot('<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>');
```

By removing the "http:" from both of the urls you are allowing the browser to choose which protocol to use.

Comment: Is this something you need to submit a pull request to https://github.com/MaxLazar/mx-google-map-v1 for?

Comment: Please do, we are dealing with this issue for several modules/addons for different reasons.

Comment: I probably will as soon as I get the chance, good idea thank you!!